# Connect quantiles in side-by-side boxplot

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, boxplot

I have a side-by-side boxplot like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
group = np.array([  np.random.binomial(2,0.4)   for _ in range(100)])
data = [  np.random.uniform(0,5)   for _ in range(len(group))]
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': data, 'group': group} )
df.boxplot(by='group', vert=False)
```

I am trying to connect the 25, 50 and 75 quantiles of these boxplots together, my desired output is something like this:

[image]

I wonder whether there is a way to do this with pandas/matplotlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
ax = df.boxplot(by='group', vert=False)

quantiles = df.groupby('group')['data'].quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75]).unstack()
for col in quantiles:
    ax.plot(quantiles[col], range(1, len(quantiles)+1), label=col)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

If you had a vertical boxplot, this would be a bit easier:

```
ax = df.boxplot(by='group', vert=True)

quantiles = df.groupby('group')['data'].quantile([0.25, 0.5, 0.75]).unstack()
quantiles.set_axis(range(1, len(quantiles)+1)).plot(ax=ax)
```

[image]